# View External HTML pages on the main page with static navigation

Tags: navigation, view, content

I am currently using SharePoint 2010.  I would like to add links to the main navigation using the site settings->look and feel-> navigation area and have those pages display within the main page of my SharePoint site.  I can get the links on the main page, but I can specify that I want the pages to display under the main nav menu area.   I am enabling certain users modify the menu of items that link to reports on a reporting server and display that content.  Any ideas how to approach this challenge?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to have those pages in the navigation point to web part pages within a document library in the site.  On those web part pages, you would add a Page Viewer web part and point it to the desired destination URL.  It will consume the external pages within an iframe on the page.